# Excel sheet connected to database - overwriting values in other columns?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet which reads data from database placed on SQL Server:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=abc;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=DATABASE1;Data Source=MYSQLEXPRESS;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=BOCZKOLENOVO;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False
```

It contains an query which reads about 5 fields. In Excel it fills columns A-E. The data are refreshed every time time the spreadsheet is opened.

I wonder what happens during refreshing with:

- data placed in other columns
- data placed in columns A-E below data from database

It seems to me that they aren't erased unless data read from database overlap them. But can I be sure about it? Anybody has experience with it?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you shouldn't put any data underneath columns A-E (to be safe), the columns F> should not be overwritten so you can utilize these.